# 90/180 rule for the spouse of an EEA citizen

Tags: schengen-visas, eu-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules, spouses

There seem to be a lot of questions around this subject, but couldn't find one specific to my case, so would really appreciate any advice or feedback.

I am spouse of an EEA national and we have been living in the UK (I am neither an EEA nor a UK national). As the spouse of an EEA national, I hold a resident permit in the UK and also have a short-stay Schengen visa.

Over the next 5 months, I would be traveling extensively to various countries in the Schengen region and will quite likely  end up spending over 90 days.

During this period, I would be traveling back and forth among those countries, traveling back to the UK, but would largely be based in Italy.

Does the same 90/180 rule still apply? If so, how strongly is it checked across borders of different countries? Can I apply for a visa under a different category - may be a business visa, to stay beyond that 90 day period?

Comment: Are you likely to still be the spouse of an EEA national on Feb 1 2020?

Comment: Yes, I will remain the spouse. Are you referring to Brexit, if so, how is that pertinent to the 90/180 rule?

Comment: Are you going to be traveling with your EEA national family member?

Comment: @Phoog: in the first instance, yes, but that might only be for a few days and then she would head back to the UK, while I would remain in Italy. However, she may join me every now and then during the entire stay, or I may join her in the UK

Comment: Is your residence permit a "residence card of a family member of a union citizen"?  To learn about merging accounts, visit https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: @phoog yes, mine is a resident card that states Family Member of EEA national. Similarly, my Schengen visa also mentions Family member of...

Comment: @Abhi with the residence card, you do not need a short-stay visa if you travel with or to join your spouse.  You also should not receive a stamp in  your passport when traveling with her or to join her.  This could work in your favor if you are ever checked for 90/180 rule compliance, because it won't be possible to determine your dates of entry and exit by looking at your passport.

Comment: @phoog: yes, I have noticed that in the past - often when we travel together, my passport is not stamped. But I always assumed that the entry and exits perhaps get registered in some central database, accessible by immigration officers across Schengen region, is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102327/discussion-between-abhi-and-phoog).

Answer (score 5):

Your short-stay Schengen visa (C-Visa) allows you to stay in the Schengen Area based on the 90/180 days rule and will be checked upon entry and exit of the Schengen Area.

Entry could be refused should they determine that you have overstayed.

A National visa (D-Visa) for a specific country (such as Italy) would be needed to stay longer. Under what conditions such a D-Visa is issued is specific to each country.

Comment: A national D visa is not required, and entry cannot be refused, when traveling with or to join the EEA spouse.  A D visa is, however, required for stays exceeding the 90/180 rule when the EEA spouse is not involved in the trip, and entry may be refused if the 90/180 rule has been exceeded and the EEA spouse is not involved in the trip.

Comment: Also, the 90/180 rule does not apply when traveling with or to join the EEA spouse, regardless of what the short-stay visa may say.  The problem, of course, is that there's no way to count the days reliably in a situation where the spouse was present for part of a visit to the Schengen area.  Because of that, in practice, passport control could be complicated, and could go well or poorly.

Comment: @phoog in that case, if my spouse accompanies me while I am entering and exiting the Schengen region, would it mean that the 90/180 rule would not apply? Even though the rest of the time she may not be with me.

Comment: @Abhi I’m slightly confused. Are you asking if the 90/180 rule applies to you or to your spouse, or both?

Comment: @Abhi as a matter of law,  you probably *are* subject to the 90/180 rule when you are not with your spouse.  But as a practical matter, if you are traveling with her, you are not likely to be checked for compliance with the 90/180 rule.

Comment: @Abhi The exception only applies to join or accompany the EEA spouse, which is not your intention. If caught out could bring consequences. You should search for a solution so you can do this based on your own rights.

Comment: @Traveller: checking whether the 90/180 applies to me.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: agree with you. What would be an alternative in this case, besides applying for a D-Visa?

Comment: @Abhi Based on what you are planning to do in Italy, get a D-Visa from Italy to do that. Then the 90/180 days rule would only apply outside of Italy, without your spouse.

Comment: @MarkJohnson what is the criteria to apply for D-Visa? I would be attending a set of seminary, workshops etc and I have been looking it up and since the objective is not to relocate there, I am not sure which category I would fall under.

Comment: @Abhi For a stay longer than 90 days (D-Visa) ; purpose attending seminary, workshops (i. e. form of study) ; financialy independent